# How to do word classification with Tensorflow tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, tflearn

I searched on the internet for a decent documentation or examples with some description, but found nothing.
What I'm trying to do, is to classify a word or little phrases (max. 3 words), and give them a priority "tag". (For example: Stephen Hawking => 1, Mr. Red => 0)
I tried to do this with Multilayer perceptron, but there I cannot use words as test data. So I'm trying to do it with RNN, using tflearn library for TensorFlow.
The problem there is that I cannot find any documentation about how I should pre-process the data, or how I should give the data to the LSTM layer.

I wrote a little bit of code:

```
data, labels = load_csv(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Machine Learning\Getting Started\Data\train_dataset_rnn.csv', categorical_labels=True, n_classes=2, delim=';')

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 1])
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, 1)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=32, show_metric=True)
```

The data has the shape => "name";0/1

When I execute this code I get this error:

```
ValueError: Invalid Activation.
```

Can someone please help me understand those layer/algorithm a little bit better?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From what i've understood, LSTM takes 3D input -> [batch_size, sequence_length, vector_representation]
In your case, you can set the sequence length to 3 (the maximum length of a sequence). I usually make a mapping from the word into the 300d GloVe representation. So the input data will look like this:

`net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3, 300])`

I'm not sure with the error, but i think you also need to specify the regression like this :

```
net = tflearn.layers.core.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.layers.estimator.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='target')
```